# Telethon (TelegramClient) — как подставить значение переменной в (Please enter your phone (or bot token): )?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telethon

При создании новой сессии в консоль выводится "Please enter your phone (or bot token): "
Можно ли как-то подставлять переменную в этот инпут в консоли автоматом?

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

api_id = 1111
api_hash = '1111111111111111111111'
name = "test"

def runn():
  with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
      result = client(functions.contacts.GetContactsRequest(hash=0))
      file2 = open(f"111.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")
      for u in result.users:
          file2.write(str(u) + '\n')

runn()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

api_id = 'id'
api_hash = 'hash'
name = 'test'
phone = '+phone'


def runn():
    with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash).start(phone) as client:
        result = client(functions.contacts.GetContactsRequest(hash=0))
        file2 = open(f"111.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")
        for u in result.users:
            file2.write(str(u) + '\n')

runn()
```